# How to chart groupby counts in pyplot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

How do I generate a pyplot line chart from the following `groupby` where the y values 
represent the counts for each 'enabled_flag' value?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-10-06', '2019-10-06','2019-10-06', '2019-10-07', '2019-10-07'], 
                   'enabled_flag': ['y', 'y','n', 'y', 'n']})

df.groupby(['date','enabled_flag'])['enabled_flag'].count()
```

So, the x-axis is 'date' and y has two axis, one for the 'Y' counts and the other for the 'N' counts.

Comment: Could you provide the code for the creation of df?

Comment: @DavideBrex - df code has been added above, thx!

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
(df.groupby(['date','enabled_flag'])['enabled_flag'].count()
   .unstack()
   .plot()
)
```

Or

```
(df.groupby('date')['enabled_flag'].value_counts()
   .unstack()
   .plot()
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: that does it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.gca().set_color_cycle(['green', 'yellow'])
for dtype in ['Y', 'N']:
  plt.plot(
     'Datetime',
     dtype,
     data=df,
     label=dtype,
     alpha=0.8
     )
plt.legend()
plt.grid() 
plt.show()
```

Try this. Does this work ?

Comment: that wasn't successful

Comment: Sorry about that